# что делать при ошибке local variable referenced before assignment?

Tags: python

**когда делал проверку вещи столкнулся с ошибкой**

```
@handler.message(name=['Угон'])
async def _(message, args, bot, user, chat, chat_user):
    ugon = get(user)
    if (user.ebyprog == 0):
        ebytexts = 'Отсутствует'
    if (user.ebyprog == 1):
        ebytexts = 'Есть'

    await user.reply(f'{user.mention()}, угоняйте автомобили:\n'
                     f' Программатор ЭБУ: {ebytexts} \n',
                     keyboard=kb, inline=True)
```

Ошибка:

```
local variable 'ebytexts' referenced before assignment File "C:\\Users\\Максимка\\Desktop\\помои\\prostobot\\app\\bot\\commands\\games\\ugon.py",
     line 51, in _\n    f\' Программатор ЭБУ: {ebytexts} \\n\',\n']
```

Comment: А что если `user.ebyprog` не будет 0 или 1? Вот у вас такая ситуация. Используйте if/elif/else или заранее определите значение переменной, чтобы не было той ошибки

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значит ваши условия не выполняются и переменная `ebytexts` не создается. А ошибка `local variable referenced before assignment` означает, что переменная, которую вы вызываете не объявлена.

Answer (score 0):

не знаком python, но судя по коду вы инициализируете ebytexts  в  условном операторе if. Но компиляторы предполагает, что программа может и не попасть в точку if,а значит переменная не сможет использоваться. Вот он и ругается.